# Efficient way to generate histogram from very large dataset in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, histogram

I have two 2D arrays of size up to `35,000*35,000` each: `indices` and `dotPs`. From this, I want to create two 1D arrays such that `pop` contains the number of times each number appears in `indices` and `nn` contains the sum of elements in `dotPs` that correspond to those numbers. I have come up with the following (really dumb) way:

```
dotPs = [81.4285    9.2648   46.3184    5.7974    4.5016    2.6779   16.0092   41.1426;
      9.2648   24.3525   11.4308   14.6598   17.9558   23.4246   19.4837   14.1173;
     46.3184   11.4308   92.9264    9.2036    2.9957    0.1164   26.5770   26.0243;
      5.7974   14.6598    9.2036   34.9984   16.2352   19.4568   31.8712    5.0732;
      4.5016   17.9558    2.9957   16.2352   19.6595   16.0678    3.5750   16.7702;
      2.6779   23.4246    0.1164   19.4568   16.0678   25.1084    6.6237   15.6188;
     16.0092   19.4837   26.5770   31.8712    3.5750    6.6237   61.6045   16.6102;
     41.1426   14.1173   26.0243    5.0732   16.7702   15.6188   16.6102   47.3289];

indices = [3     2     1     1     2     1     2     1;
           2     2     1     2     2     1     2     2;
           1     1     3     3     2     2     2     2;
           1     2     3     4     3     3     4     2;
           2     2     2     3     3     1     3     2;
           1     1     2     3     1     8     2     2;
           2     2     2     4     3     2     4     2;
           1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2];


nn = zeros(1,8);
pop = zeros(1,8);
uniqueInd = unique(indices);
for k=1:numel(uniqueInd)
    j = uniqueInd(k);
    [I,J]=find(indices==j);
    if j == 0 || numel(I) == 0
        continue
    end

    pop(j) = pop(j) + numel(I);
    nn(j) = nn(j) + sum(sum(dotPs(I,J)));
end
```

Because of the `find` function, this is very slow. How can I do this more smartly so that it runs in a few seconds rather than several minutes?

**Edit:** added small dummy matrices for testing the code.

Comment: What type of data are `pop` and `dotPs`? `double` / `uint16` / `uint8` (integers / floating point)... Also, please give a small input sample (like 8*8 not 35,000*35,000).

Comment: @Rotem done, see edits.

Comment: I think you have a bug: instead of `nn(j) = nn(j) + sum(sum(dotPs(I,J)));`, I think it should be: `nn(j) = nn(j) + sum(dotPs(sub2ind(size(dotPs), I, J)))`

Comment: @Rotem Oh, thanks for that.

Comment: I posted a smarter solution, I hope it's faster.

Answer (score 3):

Both tasks can be done with the [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) function:

```
pop = accumarray(indices(:), 1, [max(indices(:)) 1]).';
nn = accumarray(indices(:), dotPs(:), [max(indices(:)) 1]).';
```

This assumes that `indices` only contains positive integers.

---

EDIT:

From comments, only the lower part of the `indices` matrix without the diagonal should be used, and it is guaranteed to contain positive integers. In that case:

```
mask = tril(true(size(indices)), -1);
indices_masked = indices(mask);
dotPs_masked = dotPs(mask); 
pop = accumarray(indices_masked, 1, [max(indices_masked) 1]).';
nn = accumarray(indices_masked, dotPs_masked, [max(indices_masked) 1]).';
```

Comment: `indices` does contain zeros, but only on the diagonal. Since the matrix is symmetric, could we input only the upper or lower triangular part?

Comment: That's important, why wasn't that in your question text or in the example? And how should those zeros be interpreted? Should they simply be disregarded?

Comment: I have updated the answer. `indices` can now have arbitrary values, and each unique value defines a group for the count or sum

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to mention. There seems to be a problem though: this method returns `14    34    11     4     1     0     0     0`, while the answer should be `14    34    11     4     0     0     0     1`.  The `1` at the end is due to a single `8` in the matrix. `accumarray` seems to define a bin for every unique value in the array, without regard to the bin size.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate That was a mistake I made when trying to account for the zeros. Can you include an example with zeros? Or explain what types of values the `indices` can contain: only positive integers and zeros?

Comment: `indices` contains zeros on the diagonal. Everything else is positive. The matrix is symmetric -- the analysis could be done only in one of the triangular regions, if that makes things easier.

Comment: So, ignore the diagonal and keep only the lower triangular part? That will decrease count by half. And, is it assured that off-diagonal elements are positive integers?

Comment: Yes, it is assured because it's a distance matrix. It's symmetric for the same reason.

Comment: Please answer my other question too: _So, ignore the diagonal and keep only the lower triangular part?_ And, are you ok with the count being reduced by half (as a result of keeping only the lower triangular part)? Also, note that the matrix entries being distances doesn't prevent off-diagonal entries from being 0

Comment: Sorry, in my effort to provide a minimum reproducible example, I omitted a few details that are now relevant. The distance is calculated on a graph, which, by construction, does not have pair of distinct nodes of distance zero. So, the distance matrix is all positive except for diagonals. Yes, we can keep only the lower triangular part and it is okay if the count is reduced by half. Currently, we are counting each distance twice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that the dimension of `indices` does not matter (e.g. if both `indices` and `dotPs` were 1D arrays or 3D arrays the result will be the same).

`pop` can be calculated by `histcount` function, but since you also need to calculate the sum of the corresponding elements of `dotPs` array the problem becomes harder.

Here is a possible solution with a `for` loop. The advantage of this solution is that I am not calling `find` function in a loop, so it should be faster:

```
%Example input
indices=randi(5,3,3);
dotPs=rand(3,3);

%Solution
[C,ia,ic]=unique(indices);
nn=zeros(size(C));
pop=zeros(size(C));
for i=1:numel(indices)
    nn(ic(i))=nn(ic(i))+1;
    pop(ic(i))=pop(ic(i))+dotPs(i);
end
```

This solution uses a vector `ic` to categorize each of the input values. After that, I go through each element and update `nn(ic)` and `pop(ic)`.

Answer (score 1):

For computing `pop`, you can use [hist](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html), for computing `nn`, I couldn't find a smart solution (but I found a solution without using `find`):

```
pop = hist(indices(:), max(indices(:)));

nn = zeros(1,8);
uniqueInd = unique(indices);
for k=1:numel(uniqueInd)
    j = uniqueInd(k);
    nn(j) = sum(dotPs(indices == j));
end
```

There must be a better solution for computing `nn`.

---

I found a smarter solution applying sorting.

I am not sure it's faster, because sorting 35,000*35,000 elements might take a long time.

1. Sort `indices` just for getting the index for sorting `dotPs` by `indices`.
2. Sort `dotPs` according to index returned by previous sort.
3. cumsumPop = Compute cumulative sum of `pop` (cumulative sum of the histogram of `indices`).
4. cumsumPs = Compute cumulative sum of sorted `dotPs`.
5. Now values of cumsumPop can be used as indices in cumsumPs.
   Because cumsumPs is cumulative sum, we need to use `diff` 
   for getting the solution.

Here is the "smart" solution:

```
pop = hist(indices(:), max(indices(:)));

[sortedIndices, I] = sort(indices(:));
sortedDotPs = dotPs(I);

cumsumPop = cumsum(pop);
cumsumPs = cumsum(sortedDotPs);

nn = diff([0; cumsumPs(cumsumPop)]);
nn = nn';
```

Comment: You can always make use of a one liner : `arrayfun(@(x) sum(dotPs(indices==x)), 1:max(max(indices)))`. And for the first computation in a similar vein: `arrayfun(@(x) numel(indices(indices==x)), 1:max(max(indices)))`.

Comment: Thanks! I did not try the smarter way as the first one already brought it down to a few seconds (for a 2048 by 2048 array). As you said, `sort` will probably make it slower.

Comment: It turns out that sorting first cuts the runtime by half. And with this method, the runtime is scaled more weakly by the array size.